# How do I parse an RSS feed?

Tags: xml, parsing, rss

I have a simple question regarding RSS feeds and XML. I have quite a bit of experience with XML, but no experience parsing RSS feeds. From what I understand, RSS typically uses XML to transfer data. If I could get well structured XML from the website that I want to parse, I would be good to go.

The problem is that when I click on the RSS link on the site, even though the URL ends with an XML file:

```
...l.com/resources/classifieds/rss_144.xml
```

When I click on it, the website contains content that isn't structured XML at all (this is what is viewable in the browser window):

```
Classifieds : Recreational Vehicles / Motorcycles, Road Bikes Used en-us http://www....l.com/index.php?nid=231&cat=144 ...L Classifieds : Recreational Vehicles / Motorcycles, Road Bikes Used $14,900.00 : 2007 Harley Davidson Fat Boy http://www....l.com/index.php?nid=218&ad=13841365&cat=144 Start the new year off right with a new Fat Boy! I am selling my 2007 Harley Davidson Fat Boy to make room for our new baby. not only do you get a b Fri, 31 Dec 2010 15:05:42 -0700 http://www....l.com/index.php?nid=218&ad=13841365&cat=144 $1,750.00 : 1985 Honda Goldwing GL1200 Aspencade Edition - Air Rid... http://www....l.com/index.php?nid=218&ad=13841353&cat=144 1985 Honda Goldwing GL 1200 Aspencade Edition - Air Ride - Motorcycle with LOW MILES.Check out this 1985 Honda Goldwing GL1200. ONLY 53,426 miles!!! Fri, 31 Dec 2010 14:45:04 -0700
```

But as I mentioned, the url suggests this file is an XML file. I want to be able to parse through this sites content, how do I get it in a way that in manipulatable? Like with structured brackets and such?

Is there some sort of parser I need to use or something?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some browsers,  when you try to view an RSS feed, it only shows the text. Select View Source in your browser to see the actual XML.